# from Flask import Flask ImportError: No module named Flask

Tags: python, flask, filepath

I am following the tutorial [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-python-flask-and-mysql--cms-22972).

My file looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Welcome!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I run `python app.py` and get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named Flask
```

I do have flask installed. I was thinking it's a $PATH issue. I don't really know where to begin as far as troubleshooting goes.

`which flask` gives me:
`/usr/local/bin/flask`

`which python` gives me:
`/usr/bin/python`

Any help is much appreciated, there are other similar issues out there but those solutions have not helped. Happy to answer any questions. Thank you.

**Answers to questions:**

**Q.** *Which Python version?* **A.** Python 2.7.10

**Q.** *How did you install Flask?* **A.** pip install flask

Comment: It sounds like you have a package named `flask` next to `app.py`.

Comment: If pip installation didn't fail, all paths should be correct. You could check $PYTHONPATH.  @dim has a good point. Do you have a folder named `flask` or a file you named `flask.py` in the same directory?

Answer (score 3):

before run your app.py you need to activate your server by this command

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that you are using linux, if you are using ubuntu
try: (similar for other linux distributions)

```
sudo apt-get install python-flask
```

It helped me install many packages that pip fails to install.

Answer (score 1):

The `app` package and  `run.py` file need to be in the same directory level.

```
app\
    templates\
    __init__.py
venv\
run.py
```

Above folder structure should fix.

P.S. `pip install` all necessary packages into virtual enviroment (`venv` in my example)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to uninstall and to reinstall it again(you can follow this link for more detaile) :

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/installation/#installation

You can take anaconda and there you can make enviroment for every version of python .Anaconda is getting very easy from this link:
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/

Then you can open terminal and pip install flask (if you are on windows) or conda pip install flask .

I recommand to use python3.5 not python 2.7 .

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Python 3, try installing flask with

`pip3 install flask`

and if you fail (you are likely to get an command prompt error as below)

`'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

try

`py -3 -mpip install flask` on windows

this command installs flask module on python 3, and then you could run your script.
worked for me!

Answer (score -2):

Python 3 :

```py
pip3 install flask
```

Python 2 :

```py
pip install flask
```