# flash_ask not fond all overthe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

i use this code install flask

```
pip install flask
pip3 install flask
```

i import flask like this

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_ask import Ask, statement, question, session
```

when i try to run

```
python test.py
python3 test.py
```

both are give this error

```
from flask_ask import Ask, statement, question, session
ImportError: No module named flask_ask
```

try all this code

```
python3.6 -m pip install flask_openid
sudo apt-get install python-flask
```

its not solve my problem

**pip --version** : **pip 18.1  from /home/ghost/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)**

**pip3 --version**    :  **pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)**

1. [i try this answers as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask)

2.[flask installed, but ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258497/flask-installed-but-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-flask)

3. [from Flask import Flask ImportError: No module named Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989696/from-flask-import-flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've installed flask but not flask-ask which is a separate module.

```
pip install flask-ask
```

Comment: `pip install flask-ask
Collecting flask-ask
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/f5/d4709ae94584a0b1541e9b52b2d25a8a1bdb6e2da9d6870f23fdd0523a30/Flask-Ask-0.9.8.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named setuptools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-CQ8U7e/flask-ask/`

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to download flask-ask
pip install git+https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask.git@v0.8.8